# python api Can't load Str with Json.load()

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, urllib2

I've just started learning about json in python and start practicing getting bitcoin price from the website; however, I keep getting this error:

```
''Exception Value: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)''
```

When I print source it shows b' in the front of the string.  After browsing online I think it's a problem regarding byte and str stuff(also checked from an online website that the json format is indeed correct). My code is as follows:

```
import json
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/BCHARTS/BITSTAMPUSD'

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    source = response.read().decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(source)
```

Currently, I switch to

```
data = requests.get(url).json()
```

and works smoothly, still I wish to fix the above error.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because the response is in HTML format. Not in JSON format.

You can print the `source` variable and have a look.

The actual JSON is inside the `<code>` tag:

```
<html class="gr__quandl_com"><head>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <pre>
        <code>
        {...}             #Here is the actual JSON.
        </code>
    </pre>
</body>
```

You can use libs such as [beautifulsoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) to parse HTML and extract the JSON before creating the JSON object.

---

Alternatively, you can ask the server to send the response in JSON format by adding the following header while making the request:

```
request.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')
```

Comment: wow! thanks for the quick reply, gotta start digging HTML documentation...also since I can get data by `data = requests.get(url).json()` , does that mean the request package does these in the background?

Comment: Maybe. Have a look at the code inside the `requests` package. Also, if you liked my answer, I wouldn't mind an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error, because the response from the server is normal HTML and the data you're looking for is inside a `<pre>` tag. You'll have to extract the content of the `<pre>` tag or include the appropriate headers when making the request.

> From quandl API docs
>   Change Formats
>   You can get the same data in JSON format:
>
> https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/OPEC/ORB.json
>   Or in XML:
>   https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/OPEC/ORB.xml

So in your case it would be:

```
url = 'http://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/BCHARTS/BITSTAMPUSD.json'
```

Comment: thanks!! So by adding .json I'm basically telling the website that I want a specific part of the data? Or does it depend on websites?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the server, you want response in JSON format. Currently you are getting HTML.

```
import json 
import urllib.request 

url = 'http://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/BCHARTS/BITSTAMPUSD' 
request = urllib.request.Request(url) 
request.add_header('Accept', 'application/json') 
with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as response: 
     source = response.read().decode('utf-8') 
data = json.loads(source)
```